# Pushing to github without including secrete keys or passwords in a specific file for ex. app.js

Tags: node.js, git, express, github

How can you push a commit to GitHub that does not include any of your databses logins or ssh that are included in for example `app.js`?

I ask because i tried to include the file that contain the secret information into `.gitignore` but the file also contains other codes that are needed to be uploaded to GitHub for the functioning of the app should in case someone clones it or fork it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [dotenv lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Here is an example of using dotenv to keep your environment variables.

***.env***

```
SECRET=development
PORT=3002
SECRET=RC
SCRYPTPARAM=
PGHOST=0.0.0.0
PGPORT=5432
PGDATABASE=
PGUSER=postgres
PGPASSWORD=
```

An for use the env vars in your `app.js`, just call the dotenv just before using the env vars.

***app.js***

```
require('dotenv').config() // <-- here you load your env vars from .env file.
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

const app = express();
app.use('/secure', expressJwt({ secret: process.env.SECRET }));
cors({ credentials: true, origin: true });
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') { app.use(logger('dev')); }

app.use(require('./server/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

use .env file to load your environment variables

and to do so you need to:

install dotenv

```sh
yarn add dotenv
```

or

```sh
npm install dotenv
```

then create a .env file, inside it save your infos, for example

```
PASSWORD="777700"
```

then add this to your index.js file

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

dotenv.config()
```

then simply access it in your files via

```js
console.log(process.env.PASSWORD) // "777700"
```

and finally add the .env file to your .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure you have `.gitignore` entries for *any and all* configuration files. Normally I have a blanket `config/*.json` entry to avoid accidentally committing anything.

You can include "example" versions of these files that people can copy and customize to reflect their local configuration, like `config/server.json.example` or somesuch.

There's also tools like [`.env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) which have a more consistent format and use environment variables or a `.env` file to override them. That's easily ignored as well.

As always, **fully document the configuration procedure in your `README.md` file** and test periodically that the instructions are still valid.